# Acheiveing multiple colors using css3 gradients

Tags: css

How to achieve this multiple colors [image] using css3 gradients? I have seen this [website](https://do.com/users/sign_up) they have done using css3 gradients and they have only one div for that multiple colors.

Comment: You can do [CSS3 gradients](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) with multiple color stops. Just use your WebInspector/Firebug/IE-DevTools/... to have a look at that element's style declarations to see exactly what was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and place 2 stops on each 'hard' color change (e.g. place the stops both at 50%)

Comment: Good tip! I've played around a bit and look what I've made: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/n29Kh/).